# I got an error while using git commit -m "Added a Procfile" on heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I'm using heroku for deploying a python-django project.I used `git add .` command and after that I gave `git commit -m "Added a Procfile"` .I got an error

```
error: pathspec 'a' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'Procfile”' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

My procfile is like this.

```
web: gunicorn resume.wsgi --log-file -
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error shows that you are somehow using curly quotes, not straight quotes. Type your command directly into the command window rather than copying and pasting from a doc.